# Posting to a Facebook page is showing on the "POSTS TO PAGE" panel

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I got the code below from another website which seems to be working fine. The only problem is that posts appear on the "POSTS TO PAGE" section of the Facebook page instead of appearing on the page timeline directly.

Any idea why?

Also, the code works when I use the access token, not the app access token. When using app access token, I get an error message saying: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

```
<?php
// require Facebook PHP SDK
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
require_once("/YOUR_PATH_TO/facebook_php_sdk/facebook.php");

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$fb = new Facebook($config);

// define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
$params = array(
  "access_token" => "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
  "message" => "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP #php #facebook",
  "link" => "http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php",
  "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
  "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
  "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
  "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
);

// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the page settings to fix the POSTS TO PAGE issue:

> Please make sure that the Recent Posts by Others is turned on and the
>   post visibility setting is set to "Allow posts by other people on my
>   Page timeline."
>
> You can learn more about these settings in our Help Center:
>   https://www.facebook.com/help/356113237741414/?ref=u2u

Comment: This is done already but still doesn't show on timeline. See screen shot please http://www.server192.com/face.JPG

Answer (score 0):

In order to post "as Page", you need to authorize the user with `publish_pages` and `manage_pages` and use a Page Access Token, as you can read in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed#publish

Analyze the Token in the debugger to see if the page shows up: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Of course you can´t post with an App Access Token, that one does not even require authorization.

More information about Access Tokens in general:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: all the permissions are set up and I'm using a page access token and still shows on "POSTS TO PAGE".

Comment: then you are definitely not using the correct token. check it out in the debugger, i have added a link.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about tokens. Now I understand that I should use a PAGE TOKEN to be able to post to the page's timeline directly, and to get a page token you need a user token, and that means that CMS users will have to log in to Facebook before they can post articles to Facebook, right? Isn't there a way to do that without having my CMS users to log in to Facebook?? Something doesn't make sense to me. Kindly advise

Comment: of course not, that would be weird. you can´t just post to a page (as page or user) without authorizing a user, that would be a major security issue.